# Checkbox's outline not displaying in chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

We wish Chrome was better, but the reality is that it's still not as good as Firefox.

```css
.blue {
  outline: thin dotted yellow;
  outline-offset: -2px
}
```

```html
<input class="blue" type="checkbox">
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: I had a dream. Dream where everybody were using Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

you have wrong property order, correct one is:

```
.blue {
   outline: yellow dotted thin;
   outline-offset: -2px
}
```

you shouldn't blame Chrome for something that is your fault...

Answer (score 0):

You can use this hack which works in IE and in Chrome, but is not really supposed to, because `checkbox` has no content, and thus cannot have a `::before`.

```
.page input[type=checkbox].form-input-error:not([disabled])::before {
    content: ' ';
    background: transparent;
    border: 3px solid crimson;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    margin: -3px -3px;
}
```

What it does:

- Adds 3px red border
- If checkbox is not disabled
- If it has a class called `.form-input-error`

Answer (score -1):

I check it on chrome. it's okay. like this:[image]

```css
.blue {
  outline: yellow dotted thin;
  -webkit-outline: yellow dotted thin;
  outline-offset: -2px
}
```

```html
<input class="blue" type="checkbox">
```

Comment: there is no such property as `-webkit-outline`

Comment: well but my chrome display the yellow outline